# Generic Action in Play Framework controller

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I have a request form on two pages of my site: About us and Contacts. Actions for both of them described in my Home controller. 
After submitting the form I call sendRequest method, which checks form errors and sends request. This method looks like:

```
def sendRequest = Action {implicit request =>
  requestForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    formWithErrors => {
      BadRequest(views.html.Home.contacts(formWithErrors))
  },
  response => {
    Redirect(routes.HomeController.contacts().flashing("success" -> "OK"))
  }
)
```

}

In this method I define view and route to navigate. And for my About us page I should do the same work, but call about us view and route.

How could I create generic method and call it with concrete view and route as parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// if requestForm is a Form[A]

protected def genericMethod(
    view: Form[A] => play.twirl.api.Html, route: play.api.mvc.Call) = 
  Action {implicit request =>
  requestForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    formWithErrors => {
      BadRequest(view(formWithErrors))
  },
  response => {
    Redirect(route.flashing("success" -> "OK"))
  }
  )
}

def sendRequest = genericMethod(
  views.html.Home.contacts, 
  routes.HomeController.contacts())
```

Comment: In this case I still need two methods for each submission request. I meant generic method which I could call from both of my views.

Comment: I'm a little unclear about what you mean. If you're saying that you don't want to include `genericMethod` in both controllers, you can add the generic method to a companion object or trait, and then include it in both controllers.

Comment: I don't want to have several methods sendRequest in my controllers, which will set view and route. Could I send parameters for this generic method directly from my views?

Comment: No, you cannot have methods that you call from your views. It's always the controllers that call views, not the other way around.

Comment: But when I submit my form, it calls controller method. Maybe I can send view name as route parameter and get route from request or by request URL?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.